# Change Text Color after 50% height at 175deg

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

I am changing background color after 50% height with 175deg angle.So, I want the text color to become white, when the background-color is blue. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h7jhcbm0/3/)

```css
.bg {
      background: linear-gradient(175deg, #e2e2e2 50%, #435289 50%);
      color:#000;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
<h1>
 Hiii, My Name is John, I love Stackoverflow. I really don't know, how to do this, Can someone help me? If Background = Blue, Text Color = White
</h1>
  
</div>


</div>
```

Comment: Try not to just ask for someone to complete your code, show your research what have you done to try and resolve this issue yourself?

Comment: what have you tried in this regard ? to solve your problem ?  i see you included javascript as a tag to your question. where is the javascript ?

Comment: When background-color = Blue, Text color changes to White. Is it possible? How?

Comment: I tried nothing, because I have no idea. I am not askign to write you a code, but give me some hints please. I did my research, but i cannot find anything like this on the internet

Comment: There is no trivial way to achieve this using HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New answer:

Set the background of the `h1` element using linear-gradient in the same shape, but the colors you want for the text. Than make the text color transparent, and use `background-clip: text` (note the [browser's compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip#Browser_compatibility)) to color the text.

```css
.bg {
  background: linear-gradient(175deg, #e2e2e2 50%, #435289 50%);
  color: #000;
}

h1 {
  color: transparent;
  background: linear-gradient(175deg, #435289 50%, white 50%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <h1>
    Hiii, My Name is John, I love Stackoverflow. I really don't know, how to do this, Can someone help me? If Background = Blue, Text Color = White
  </h1>

</div>


</div>
```

**Original answer:**

If you need the contrast, and not the exact colors, you can use [`mix-blend-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode) to dynamically change the color according to the background:

```css
.bg {
  background: linear-gradient(175deg, #e2e2e2 50%, #435289 50%);
  color: #000;
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <h1>
    Hiii, My Name is John, I love Stackoverflow. I really don't know, how to do this, Can someone help me? If Background = Blue, Text Color = White
  </h1>

</div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can specifically apply that color. see
https://jsfiddle.net/h7jhcbm0/2/

```
.bg {
  background: linear-gradient(175deg, #e2e2e2 50%, #435289 50%);
  color: #000;
}

h3 {
  color: #fff
}
```

Comment: This is exactly working as you described it..... Text = white when background = blue

Comment: i dnt think there is any easy way of doing that in css.

Comment: i like @Ori 's answer but check browser compatibility if that is critical to you.

Comment: @tech2017 is right - look at the bottom article about mix-blend-mode (link in the answer)